# Deriving edges when not continuous

Tags: computer-vision, emgucv, edge-detection

I'm new in computer vision.
I'm doing a project where I need to obtain a binary hand from a picture.
I uploaded an example. From **picture 1** I want to obtain **picture 2**.

[image: Example]

I applied canny edge detector to **picture 1** but I obtained **picture 3** in the example.
I'm using EmguCV for it.

```
Image<Gray, Byte> imgaux = new Image<Gray, Byte>("example.bmp");
imgaux = imgaux.Canny(100, 300);
```

My problem is that I don't have continuous edges, so I can't fill the hand to obtain **picture 2**.
What approach could be used to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is apply `Gaussian Blur` on image 2 , so that the image is smooth and then apply the `canny edge detection` method.

so the code might look something like this.

```
Image<Gray, Byte> imgaux = new Image<Gray, Byte>("example.bmp");
imgaux = imgaux .SmoothGaussian(3,3,34.3,45.3);
imgaux =imgaux.Canny(100, 300);
```

You can play around with the values in the SmoothGaussian function's parameters  to match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at chapter 3 of [this paper](http://www.best-of-robotics.org/pages/BRICS-events/icra2010/BLORT2010Moerwald.pdf) than you can see that they do some postprocessing quite similar as to what you requested. Even though their aim is to do perceptual grouping I think the procedure describe should fit your needs. You might want to combine this approach with @Shiva's to get even better results. But beware that you're still not guaranteed to get a continuous contour that you can just fill.

Bresenham Line Drawing is even implemented in the `line()` function which lies in the OpenCV Drawing Function package.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to canny edge detection would be to go for Local binary pattern based techniques.
You can use [this](http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/Downloads/LBPMatlab) to verify your need and implement the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would apply a `median filter` on image (2) with a large enough kernel that will make the contour of the hand smooth. The size of the hand might change **a bit** but as every image contains some sort of noise, this should not impact your final results in case you are going to process it afterwards.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. Picture 2 is my target. I don't have it.
I have Picture 1 and I could obtain Picture 3 with an edge detector.